# Error when trying to capture screenshot of a webpage using Python on Windows

Tags: python

I'm getting an error when trying to capture a screenshot of a webpage in Python 3.6. Tried following other posts where the same question was posed, but none of it helped. Please guide as in where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.python.org/')
driver.save_screenshot('python_org.png')
driver.quit()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-  packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/screen_capture_3.py", line 3, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-    packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 145, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver'    executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)